# Responsive segmented dropdown group with block level input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'am using bootstrap framework to develop a Responsive Hotel Search page. I need a segmented dropdown group with block level input as shown in below image.

[image: Sample image i need]

Here, The input will be full width, Floated left to Action dropdown.
The Text "Action" is dynamic and will change according to user selects from the dropdown. so the width of dropdown may increase.

The input text should only start from just left to the dropdown and fits to full width also.

I managed with this static, but there are lot of issues i faced with width when doing responsive and when the dropdown text increased.

does anyone have any idea how to implement this ?

Advanced thanks for the help..

Edit : here is a Js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/mP8ab/

HTML

```
<form class="bs-docs-example">
            <div class="input-prepend">
              <div class="btn-group" style="
    z-index: 1;
">
                <button class="btn" tabindex="-1">Action</button>
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
            </div>

          </form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code and/or a JSFiddle?

Comment: i have added jsfiddle check it out http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/mP8ab/